# Android - how to track when my app crashes on a device where it is downloaded?

Tags: android

Someone emailed me today that my app crashed on their device. I could not reproduce it on my device. Is there any way to get the error report when my app has problems on another device?

Thanks!

Comment: The user can upload a crash report which should include the stack trace. They can also add user comments to perhaps explain what they were doing at the time. Other than that, use one of the crash-reporting systems such as ACRA http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/acra/

is one possible way. To get going you have to add the library to your project, and make a  form on your google docs account. Once you are set up a new row gets added to the spreadsheet whenever the app crashes. It can give you lots of information about the environment and situation in which the app crashed.